# Как правильно блокировать записи в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, многопоточность

Есть таблица с данными.
Приложение в многопоточном режиме обращается в таблице и берет строки из нее для обработки, после обработки строка должна быть обновлена.

1. Как избежать того что 2 потока возьмут в работу одну и ту же строку?
2. Что будет если приложение прервется с ошибкой во время обработки строк? Взятые в работу строки будут заблокированы СУБД? Как избежать проблем с этим на случай вылета приложения?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Думаю, тут подойдёт паттерн Produser-Consumer. Один поток читает данные из БД и помещает их в потокобезопасную коллекцию. Другой поток (или потоки) берёт данные из этой коллекции и обрабатывает. После чего помещает данные в другую потокобезопасную коллекцию. Ещё один поток выбирает обработанные данные и пишет в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. В транзакции делайте запрос типа такого, чтоб выбрать какое-то количество записей для обработки

```
SELECT * 
FROM job_queue FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
ORDER BY some_field
LIMIT <batch_size>
```

Обработав записи делайте обычный UPDATE записей которые выбрал запрос ранее, ну там помечайте статус, что они уже обработаны или вообще удаляйте их (главное чтоб новый SELECT запрос их не получал), и фиксируйте транзакцию (делайте commit).

Тут `SKIP LOCKED` как раз избегает проблемы #1, т.е. того, что два обработчика возьмут одну и ту же запись.

Если приложение прервется с ошибкой, то транзакция автоматически откатится базой данных и все заблокированные записи освободятся, и другие обработчики смогут их взять в обработку.