# Очередь или возможность "запирания" в PHP или MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, очередь

Есть некая таблица `queue`, она по запросу отдает `unique.ciphertext` и "запирает" этот `ciphertext` на определенное время. Чтобы по другим запросам не возвращало данные записи. Это достигалось так: у каждой записи есть поле `blockedtill`, после считывания идет обновление  `blockedtill = now() + interval 2 minute`.

Проблема: Одновременно работают 10+ потоков, и приблизительно в 40% "замыкание" не срабатывает, так как следующие запросы успевают получить те же `ciphertext` до того как запишется новое значение в `blockedtill`.

Пытался решить проблему так, не сработало:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLES `queue` WRITE;
SELECT `ciphertext` FROM `queue` WHERE ...;
UPDATE `queue` SET `blockedtill` = NOW() + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE WHERE ...;
COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать или есть ли готовая реализация очереди на PHP, MySQL?

Comment: "запирать" записи таким странным способом вообще не нужно. Вам надо использовать `select ... for update` и БД за вас заблокирует запись до тех пор пока вы не дадите commit. Но по умолчанию другие обработчики которые пытаются прочитать такие записи (то же с for update) то же будут заблокированы, что бы этого не происходило надо добавить еще к запросу 'skip locked'

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1432520/194569

Answer (score 1):

Это обычное резервирование за потоком.

Легко решается введением поля `processed_by`, которое содержит NULL, если запись ещё никем не взята, -1, если запись уже обработана, и значение `CONNECTION_ID()`, если она обрабатывается соединением.

Соответственно чтобы взять запись на обработку, выполняем

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET processed_by = CONNECTION_ID()
-- ORDER BY {expression}
LIMIT 1;
```

после чего проверяем, получилось или нет, запросом

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE processed_by = CONNECTION_ID();
```

Возможные варианты:

- ноль записей - значит, запись перехватил конкурент. повторяем попытку резервирования;
- одна запись - резервирование успешно, приступаем к обработке;
- более одной записи - проблема, зовём оператора.

При этом blocked_till не требуется. Однако в структуре должно быть автообновляемое поле `updated_at`. Его назначение - по нему определить, что запись "подвисла" (зарезервировавший запись поток не выполнил обработку по сбою или иным причинам). И соответственно такие записи возвращаются в пул необработанных из Event procedure сбросом поля `processed_by` в NULL.